# Want to integrated Facebook Like

Tags: javascript, facebook-like

I tried to integrated the Facebook Like in my website.
I tried as mentioned in the facebook social plugins just as below.

```
    <body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

Like: 
<fb:like href="https://www.facebook.com/testos1234" layout="standard" action="like" show_faces="true" share="true"></fb:like>
```

or

```
 </body>
```

But couldn't find anything when i run that html page in browser.
Please help.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Pradeep.

Comment: can you do a jsfiddle ?

Comment: ya tried with that as well still can see the output. Can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the html tag to insert the xml namespace?

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

It is mandatory on using XFBML syntax

Comment: yes i have mentioned that as well but still not working. Its not working even when i use HTML5 code.

Comment: Thanks @Mardie ya its working but Y the same code not working in the browser, but its working in jsfiddle.

what to do now.

Comment: You can copy-paste jsfiddle code to a local file for testing.
I suggest you to try it on different browsers and diferent servers (you can use tools like LAMP for local) for focus on the error. It looks like a client configuration error since code works.

Comment: I just want to know what is LAMP tool ?